# Objectify cache hit/miss and quotas

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I have launched a new web app this month. I'm trying to understand why I'm getting such a high datastore read value, even though all my entities are cached.

So, my main point of misunderstanding is this. in the total quota overview for this month I have 1.12 M read operations in the datastore.

But when I go to the memcache section in the console, it tells me the hit ratio is 96.35% and the numbers are: 1,457,499 hit / 55,177 miss

First of all, is it true that these numbers are per month or are they per day?

Second, how is this possible?

I know that reads in transactions don't user the cache. But I do not make heavy use of transactions. Is there anything other than transactions that can cause this?

Comment: When you say "Is there anything other than transactions that can cause this?" do you mean anything that can cause cache misses?  The main thing will be objects being evicted from the cache.  Do you have shared or dedicated memcache?  Have you tried tracing your top requests through Appstats?

Answer (score 2):

If you want more insight into your Objectify memcache hit rates, mount the MemcacheStatsServlet (or look at its code and do something similar). This will provide your cache hit ratio broken down by Kind.

Keep in mind that since it is reporting for just one instance (whichever you happen to hit with your request for stats), this is only a representative sample of what is going on in your cluster.